# Is it possible to use the parameters in a Jenkins parameterized build in the SCM URL?

Tags: jenkins

I wanted to use the value of a parameter in a parameterized build as part of the Repository URL and Local Module directory in the SCM of Jenkins.[sample job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef2vO.png)

Please let me know if it is possible and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

The option is in General tab, "This build is parameterized". It's built-in.

Your choice of parameter type, the name of the parameter is the variable to use. eg:

```
http://path.to.repo/${projectName}
```

Takes the first/default value if triggered by web hook or timer.

We use for both dynamic repo and branch selection.

There's also plugin [build with parameters](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters), (no experience) similar but different. There are additional similar parameter plugins too.